# Mock call not being detected

Tags: c++, trompeloeil

I created a test case with Catch2 and I am trying to use TrompeLoeil for finer testing.
However the mock calls either don't happen at all, or happen but don't seem to be detecting by the framework.

Here is a minimal reproductible example :

```
class MyRealClass
{
public:
    virtual int returnSumOfValues(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};

class MyMockClass : public MyRealClass
{
public:

    MAKE_MOCK2(returnSumOfValues, int(int,int));
};

class MyTestedClass
{
public:
    MyTestedClass(MyRealClass* _computeObj)
        : computeObj(_computeObj)
    {
    }

    int compute()
    {
        return computeObj->returnSumOfValues(2,3);
    }

    MyRealClass* computeObj;
};

TEST_CASE("Testing Trompe L'oeil")
{
    auto mock = new MyMockClass();
    MyTestedClass testedClass(mock);

    int val = testedClass.compute();

    CHECK(val == 5);
    REQUIRE_CALL(*mock, returnSumOfValues(2,3)).RETURN(5);
}
```

And here is the error I get from running this test :

> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Testing Trompe L'oeil
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ../../../src/MEGAAutoTests/UnitTests/control/TransferBatchTests.cpp:164
> ...............................................................................
>
> ../../../src/MEGAAutoTests/UnitTests/main.cpp:38: FAILED: explicitly
> with message:   No match for call of returnSumOfValues with signature
> int(int,int) with.
> param  _1 == 2
> param  _2 == 3

I debugged this step by step and the mocked `returnSumOfValues()` is the one being executed.

However, if I make `MyRealClass::returnSumOfValues()` not virtual, **the mock class is not used at all**.

And the error is :

> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Testing Trompe L'oeil
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ../../../src/MEGAAutoTests/UnitTests/control/TransferBatchTests.cpp:164
> ...............................................................................
>
> ../../../src/MEGAAutoTests/UnitTests/main.cpp:43: FAILED:   CHECK(
> failure.empty() ) with expansion:   false with message:   failure :=
> "../../../src/MEGAAutoTests/UnitTests/control/TransferBatchTests.
> cpp:172   Unfulfilled expectation:   Expected
> *mock.returnSumOfValues(2,3) to be called once, actually never   called
> param  _1 == 2
> param  _2 == 3   "

This seems to not be consistent with [the official documentation](https://github.com/rollbear/trompeloeil/blob/main/docs/CookBook.md/#custom_formatting), which states that :

> The line MAKE_MOCK2(log, void(int severity, const std::string& msg))
> creates a mock function void Logger::log(int, const std::string&). If
> MAKE_MOCKn(...) or MAKE_CONST_MOCKn(...) are used to implement a
> virtual function from a base class, **it is always recommended to add a
> third macro parameter override** since it gives the compiler an ability
> to complain about mistakes.

**Recommended**, not **required**. And to give the compiler more information, not to make the test work.

**TL, DR**

1. Why is my code sample not working?
2. Why do I need to make mocked functions virtual when the documentation suggests it is not mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that **expectations need to be set beforehand**.

I though they worked like assertions, checking a state after the code was executed, but this is not the case.

In this case, moving the call solved the problem. Here is the fixed code sample :

```
TEST_CASE("Testing Trompe L'oeil")
{
    auto mock = new MyMockClass();
    MyTestedClass testedClass(mock);
    REQUIRE_CALL(*mock, returnSumOfValues(2,3)).RETURN(5);

    int val = testedClass.compute();

    CHECK(val == 5);
}
```

This is the solution to the first problem, the second one (only virtual functions can be mocked) remains unanswered.